# Implement a trait for another trait Item type

Tags: error-handling, rust

I need to convert a parse error to my own Error type while returning Result. Simplified, it looks like the following:

```
enum MyError {
    Parse,
    ...,
}

fn process<R: FromStr>(s: &str) -> Result<(), MyError> {
    Ok(s.parse::<R>()?)
}
```

For above to work From trait should be implemented. This doesn't work:

```
impl From<std::str::FromStr::Err> for MyError {
    fn from(e: std::str::FromStr::Err) -> MyError {
        MyError::Parse
    }
}
```

The compiler diagnostics:

```
help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Type as std::str::FromStr>::Err`
```

But I don't know the exact `Type` here. The whole point is to allow conversion from all possible errors.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without making `MyError` generic. `FromStr::Err` isn't a concrete type, it's a type specified by implementations of `FromStr`, which means you can't refer to it as if it were a concrete type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're discarding the parse error anyway, use [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) to change the error locally:

```
fn process<R: FromStr>(s: &str) -> Result<(), MyError> {
    let _ = s.parse::<R>().map_err(|_| MyError::Parse)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type `FromStr::Err` is an *associated type* of the `FromStr` trait. Every implementation of `FromStr` has its own associated type, and this type is completely unconstrained – it could be any type at all. This means you would need a conversion from any type to `MyError` to achieve what you want:

```
impl<T> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(e: T) -> MyError {
        MyError::Parse
    }
}
```

However, this implementation is disallowed by the coherence rules – it conflicts with the implementation of `From<T>` for any type `T` in the standard library. And even if this implementation was allowed, it wouldn't really do what you want – *any* error type would be converted to `MyError::Parse`, not just parse errors.

One possible workaround is to introduce a marker trait for parse error types:

```
trait ParseError {}

impl<T: ParseError> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(e: T) -> MyError {
        MyError::Parse
    }
}
```

You can then implement this marker trait for all parse error types:

```
impl ParseError for std::str::ParseBoolError {}
impl ParseError for std::num::ParseFloatError {}
impl ParseError for std::num::ParseIntError {}
impl ParseError for std::net::AddrParseError {}
impl ParseError for std::char::ParseCharError {}
```